# How to use mapDispatchToProps and Reducers in redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

> this is file app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
import reducers from './reducers'

const store = createStore(reducers)
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

> this is reducers

```
let defaultState = []
export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action){
   switch(action.type){
       case 'ADD_TODO':
           return {
               defaultState : [...state, action.text] 
           }
       default:
           return state
   }
}
```

> this is file item.js

```
.......
import addTodo from './action'
class Item extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.inputRef = createRef()
    }
    render() { 
        return (
        <>
            <input ref = {this.inputRef} type = 'text'></input>
            <button onClick = {() => this.props.add(this.inputRef.current.value)} type= 'button' >Add Todo</button> 
            {this.props.todoList.map(item => <h5>{item}</h5>) } 
            {/* this is error */}
        </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      todoList : state
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
   return {
    add : (text) => dispatch(addTodo(text))
   }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Item)
```

> this is file action.js

```
const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO'
 const addToto = (text) => {
    return {
        type : ADD_TODO,
        text
    }
}
export default addToto;
```

> Error : this.props.todoList.map is not a function
>   i want to add new item when i onClick in button addtodo then display on tag h5.
>   and check for me when i get value from tag input , IT's TRUE

Answer (score 1):

Your defaultState is an array and you are returning object in `ADD_TODO`.

**Fix**

```js
let defaultState = []
export default function reducer(state = defaultState, action){
   switch(action.type){
       case 'ADD_TODO':
           return [...state, action.text] //<---- see here
       default:
           return state
   }
}
```

**Edit**
Also you need to use `current` to access the value of ref

```js
<button onClick = {() => this.props.add(this.inputRef.current.value)} type= 'button' >Add Todo</button>
```

Comment: i fixed like you and change my post, now it has error : this.props.todoList.map is not a function when i onclick button Add Todo

Comment: just found another issue in ur code... i have updated the answer .... also are you using combineReducer? if so , you need to adjust `mapStateToProps` ..... share the configuration of store..

Comment: i shared file app.js , i fixed above but i still met error :  this.props.todoList.map is not a function , When i onClick in button Add Todo